# Filtering a database based on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I want to filter my Firebase query by the checkbox the user picks. I was thinking to do it with checkboxes, but not it doesn't seem like such a good idea.

Here's my code:

```
handleCheckboxChange(value) {
    console.log(value);
}


<form style={{marginTop: 100}}>
    <FormGroup
        controlId="formBasicText">
        <ControlLabel>Working example with validation</ControlLabel>
        <FormGroup>
            <Checkbox onChange={() => this.handleCheckboxChange('Primary School')} inline>Primary
                School</Checkbox>
            <Checkbox inline>Middle School</Checkbox>
            <Checkbox inline>High School</Checkbox>
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup>
            <Checkbox inline>Math</Checkbox>
            <Checkbox inline>Chinese</Checkbox>
            <Checkbox inline>History</Checkbox>
            <Checkbox inline>Physics</Checkbox>
            <Checkbox inline>Chemistry</Checkbox>
            <Checkbox inline>Biology</Checkbox>
            <Checkbox inline>Geography</Checkbox>
            <Checkbox inline>English</Checkbox>
            <Checkbox inline>German</Checkbox>
            <Checkbox inline>Spanish</Checkbox>
            <Checkbox inline>Something</Checkbox>
            <Checkbox inline>Else</Checkbox>
            <Checkbox inline>IT</Checkbox>
            <Checkbox inline>Other</Checkbox>
        </FormGroup>
    </FormGroup>
</form>
```

These are the checkboxes. So the problem is, I need to get the values like `Primary School`, `Biology` and so on, and use them to filter my db. But I have no idea how to get them the right way. If I pass it as a function parameter (like in the `Primary School` example) it means I have to do everything twice, which makes no sense.

So my question is: How can I get the values of the `Checkbox` element, without passing it to a function every time?

The `Checkbox` element is using [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/). It renders out to:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline" title="">
<input type="checkbox">Primary School</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all those options to some array

`const OPTIONS = ["Math", "Chinese", "History", "Physics", ...];`

and from this array create list of checkbox like that:

```
<FormGroup>
{OPTIONS.map((option, index) => (
    <Checkbox
        key={index}
        title={option}
        value={option}
       checked={this.state.options.includes(option)}
       onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
    />
 ))}
```

and to manage values inside handleCheckboxChange you need to create state inside your component, it can be for example this.state = { options: [" "] } , and add/remove values to array of options like that

```
handleCheckbox = e => {
    let val = e.target.value;
    console.log({val});
    if (this.state.options.includes(val)) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            options: prevState.options.filter(option => option !== val)
        }));
    } else {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            options: [...prevState.options, val]
        }));
    }
};
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Actually I have one question. When I run the `handleCheckbox` code, it acts weird. If I add `console.log(this.state.options)` at the end I get it one step behind. Example: If I click `History` I get `Array []`. Then if I click `History` again (it's unchecked now) I get: `Array [ "History" ]`. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: checkout react docs about `setState` https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate or this article https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b

if you want to read setState after update it you can pass to setState callback function like this `this.setState({options: [""], () => { console.log(this.state.options) }}`

Comment: Well ok then, now it works. I guess async has something to do with it. Dzięki!